# Symlink between different drives doesn't work

Tags: windows, symbolic-link

I have a folder which I want to move from `D:\` to `C:\` drive (they are two physical drives) without breaking anything that uses this folder. Following some guide I moved my folder to `C:\` and tried to create a symlink from `D:\folder` to `C:\folder`. It reports success, I can open created link as a folder and see a list of subfolders, but I can't open any of subfolder or file. Here is console log:

```
D:\>mklink /D D:\dev C:\dev
symbolic link created for D:\dev <<===>> C:\dev

D:\>cd dev

D:\dev>dir
 Volume in drive D has no label.
 Volume Serial Number is 2C97-9F5E

 Directory of D:\dev

(Here is a correct list of my subfolders)
               0 File(s)              0 bytes
              38 Dir(s)  77,532,950,528 bytes free

D:\dev>cd subfolder
The system cannot move the file to a different disk drive.
```

(tried `mklink /J` as well, same result)

I also tried some other software for this (xcopy, Symlinker, Link Shell Extension), but all of them either fail to create a link between two drives, or create it with the same result as `mklink`.

I also created a link within one drive and it worked properly.

I saw other people successfully making a link between drives, but for some reason it doesn't work for me. If it makes any difference - I use Windows 10, `C:\` is a system SSD and `D:\` is HDD. Both have NTFS.

Comment: Did you try creating Directory Junctions with `/J` example `mklink /J D:\dev/examplefolder C:\dev\Examplefolder` and then see if you can access the sub folder. Then repeat with the other sub folders.

Comment: @NetworkKingPin Just tried with the same result - can create link and open it, but can't access anything inside it

Comment: This is unfortunately a limit of the links on Windows.  The implementation is pretty functional for GUI applets as you noticed, but will probably always be limited for command line usage.

Comment: Sorry, a bit late to answer. If you use the tool [Link Shell Extension](http://schinagl.priv.at/nt/hardlinkshellext/hardlinkshellext.html), it has various copy/mirror/clone options one of which will probably do what you want.

Comment: @JulianKnight As mentioned in the question, I tried this tool as well and it didn't work.

Comment: Did you try the various modes?

Comment: Junction works just fine for me for linking an apparent folder on C: to a folder on USB drive E:. This is in Windows 10. I think I used that also in WIndows 7.